# Azure service that can process TCP message on none

Tags: azure, tcplistener

I am looking to rewrite a legacy windows based system to make use of Azure serverless features. Issue I have is that the system has to receive messages coming in via TCP due to the upstream system only supporting that approach.  The upstream system then receives the ACK of the handshake as confirmation the message has been accepted.

Are there any Azure services that can accept a TCP message on a none standard port that I could then use to place the message on to an Azure queue?  I have found some articles using Service Fabric but nothing less than 3 years old so wonder if there is a better way of doing it currently?

Comment: Azure functions are started using a trigger. So basically you need a TPC Trigger. As far as I know, there is no such trigger. You CAN however write your own trigger but I don't recommend that path. I recon you investigate for a different approach and leave the Azure Functions idea

Answer (score 0):

So you can use [IoT Hub Protocol Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-protocol-gateway) which can be the middle-man for accepting TCP\UDP messages which can then forward the message to Event\IoT Hub. You can then use [Event Hub trigger in Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs) to process your messages.

You can deploy the Protocol Gateway on an Azure VM.